# What's the difference between "Mathematica Home Edition" and "Mathematica Personal Use"?

Tags: installation, licensing

I purchased a Home Edition of Mathematica, which I understand is only available for personal use.

But when I try to download it, I get two different options for the "Home Edition" and "Personal use":
[image]

The two different options have different license numbers listed. What is the difference between these two options, and which one should I download?

Comment: I pay for the option that gives me both a home and personal edition - so I can load Mathematica on two physically different machines. Otherwise, they are identical.

Comment: @Moo That's odd - you get exactly two machines? There's no way to do three?

Comment: I am not sure they will do that, but you have to work it out for three separate licenses at some cost. You would have to contact and discuss as it may require buying a whole separate license.

Comment: Recall, **a license** = **a machine**. So, you have to purchase $x$ of them for $x$ machines.

Comment: @Moo Yeah that makes sense. It’s just odd because Wolfram didn’t give me any indication that I’d be getting two different licenses - I was only expecting one - and the fact that they’re identical but have different descriptions is very strange to me.

Comment: Mine each have a different license code for tracking.

Comment: It is in the situation when an enterprise buys a commercial license of Mathematica for its employee, Wolfram gives the latter a Home Edition for free to enable the employee to work also at home.